# sympy.lcm not expanding terms correctly

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to find the LCM of two terms using sympy. The code I am using is:

```
import sympy
s=sympy.Symbol("s")
A=(s+0.0004)*(s+0.02)
B=(s+0.02)
sympy.lcm(A,B)
```

which returns

```
1.0*s**2 + 0.0204*s + 7.99999999999992e-6
```

However, by inspection the lcm should be

```
1.0*s**2 + 0.0204*s + 8.0e-6
```

How can I get the sympy.lcm to compute the exact solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that 0.02 and 0.004 do not have a finite exact representation as floats, so you are having issues with rounding even before you start. You can keep these numbers exact by using `sympy.Rational`s:

```
A = (s + sympy.Rational(4, 1000))*(s + sympy.Rational(2, 100))
B = (s + sympy.Rational(2, 100))
sympy.lcm(A, B).expand()
```

This now gives an exact result:

```
s**2 + 3*s/125 + 1/12500
```